# How Apache Spark uses .crc files

Tags: apache-spark, crc

When spark writes files to output destination, it writes files with the extension .crc (e.g: part-r-1.parquet.crc). How Apache Spark uses .crc files?

"CRCs are specifically designed to protect against common types of errors on communication channels, where they can provide quick and reasonable assurance of the integrity of messages delivered. However, they are not suitable for protecting against intentional alteration of data.

Firstly, as there is no authentication, an attacker can edit a message and recompute the CRC without the substitution being detected"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check

It appears that Spark uses .crc files to ensure that the data in files transferred between nodes is intact. But I don't know how he uses it exactly

Comment: In general, the CRC is calculated on the received file, and then compared to the CRC that was sent along with the file. If it matches, the received file is most likely ok. If it does not match, then the received file is definitely corrupted.